# Integrate with the definition $\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^x\sqrt{1-e^x}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

I am sorry for not providing any *suggestion* or info, but I really don't know where to start. I think that it could be related to **Riemann Sum**, but I don't have a clue about how to do this. I would really appreciate any kind of help. $$\int_{-\infty}^0 e^x\sqrt{1-e^x} \, dx$$

Comment: Careful, this is an improper integral..Also, I think it is missing a $dx$.

Comment: Hint (for the indefinite integral):  try a substitution.

Comment: I think that I know how to integrate it, but I'm asked to do it using the definition, and that's my problem!

Comment: What do you call "the definition"?

Comment: I wrote in the text of the question; I mean using Riemann Sums!

Comment: :-/ you want to use Riemann sums?  On that?!  Is that a reasonable question to answer, or shouldn't you be a tad more fair...?

Comment: If you see the tags, there is "riemann-sum" and "riemann-integration", so I think it shouldn't be so a tad more fair! (Or, even better, you should ask my Calculus-Teacher!)

Answer (score 1):

Change of variable $u=e^x$ leads to :

$$\int_{-\infty}^0e^x\sqrt{1-e^x}\,dx=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-u}\,du$$

This last integral is easy to compute !

Comment: I think that I know how to integrate it, but I'm asked to do it using definition (see title), and that means using Riemann Sum!

Comment: @L.Repetti: good luck. That is both difficult and useless, given the fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I asked here because I have this exercise in one of the exam theme of my calculus course ("Analisi 1"), and so I thought to ask here because I really don't know how to do it. If this is inappropriate, I'll delete the question!

Comment: @L.Repetti: was it the exercise about proving the Riemann-integrability of the given function, or about finding the exact value of the integral, through Riemann sums? The difficulty is **very** different. Potresti allegare il testo esatto? Sono scettico sul fatto che qualcuno chieda di determinare il valore di quell'integrale via somme di Riemann. Finché si tratta di polinomi ok, ma qui è dura...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The exact text is the following: "Calcolare con la definizione il seguente integrale : $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^x\sqrt{1-e^x} \, dx$". Mando una Mail al docente per accertarmi del significato se la difficoltà è così alta, in nessun integrale precedente ho trovato scritto "con la definizione"  e quindi ho pensato alle somme di Riemann. I didn't thought it was **so** difficult.  Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: @L.Repetti: immagino che *con la definizione* si intenda *con la definizione di integrale di Riemann improprio*, e il Teorema Fondamentale del Calcolo sia ammesso. Anche perché gli integrali di Riemann sono definiti come limiti di somme di Riemann solo se l'intervallo di integrazione è compatto, se l'intervallo di integrazione è $\mathbb{R}^-$ bisogna comunque passare ad un limite. Calcolare $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}\,dx$ via somme di Riemann non è difficile, basta il binomio di Newton in forma estesa, ma prima c'è da legittimare la cruciale sostituzione $e^x=u$.

Comment: @L.Repetti: oppure basta rendersi conto che $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}\,dx$ è il complementare dell'area di un segmento parabolico, la cui area si può determinare con argomentazioni puramente geometriche (grazie, Archimede!). In ogni caso, *thousand ways to skin a cat*, e forse è davvero il caso di chiedere al professore cosa pretendeva davvero. Dove studi, per curiosità?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  Grazie mille per le risposte (chiederò al docente domani!), apprezzo questo sito proprio per l'infinità di soluzioni diverse che vengono date ad ogni singolo problema! Studio ingegneria informatica al Politecnico di Milano, al primo anno. Colgo l'occasione per complimentarmi per MateMate e per la tua utilissima attività su stack!

Answer (score -1):

If I want to give a HINT for this kind of thing, here's what I write:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 \sqrt{1-e^x} \Big(e^x\,dx\Big).
$$
That should suggest $du = e^x\,dx.$ Rather than write $u=e^x$ as in "Adren"'s answer, I'll go with $u=1-e^x$ so that $du = -e^x\,dx$ and the expression in the big parentheses is $-du$. Then we have
$$
\int_\text{?}^\text{?} \sqrt u \big( {-du}\big)
$$
and we need to figure out what to put where the two question marks are. When $x=0$ then $u=1-e^0=0.$ As as $x\to-\infty$ then $e^x\to0$ so $u\to1.$ We get
$$
\int_1^0 \sqrt u \big( {-du}\big) = \int_0^1 \sqrt u \, du =\cdots\cdots
$$